# Google Cloud Shell JSON (error 400) problem when making Cloud Vision API connection

Tags: json, shell, google-cloud-platform, curl, google-vision

I am trying to locate objects in a given picture (base64) by using Google Cloud Vision API as a newbie. I am using Google Cloud shell environment for this purpose and keeping all the files (image file and JSON file) in this Shell environment. When I run the `Curl` command with the parameters below, I get  error all the time:

`curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"  -H "x-goog-user-project: cogent-anvil-417312" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data-binary -d @request.json "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate"`

> **Error Code:**  400
> **Message:** "Invalid JSON payload received. Unable to parse number.\n-d\n^"
> **Status:** "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

I would be grateful if someone could help me out for this issue:

I tried the following on the Google Cloud Shell but could not find a solution to avoid this INVALID_ARGUMENT problem. You can see content of the JSON file below as well.

```bash
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$ clear
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$ pwd
/home/ccamkoy/aidat
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$ ls -al
total 192
drwxr-xr-x 2 ccamkoy ccamkoy   4096 Mar 16 01:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 ccamkoy ccamkoy   4096 Mar 16 01:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ccamkoy ccamkoy 182129 Mar 16 00:22 IMG_2058_1024x768.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ccamkoy ccamkoy    240 Mar 16 01:06 request.json
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$ base64 IMG_2058_1024x768.jpeg -w 0 > IMG_2058_1024x768_Base64.jpeg                               
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$ ls -al                                                                                           
total 432
drwxr-xr-x 2 ccamkoy ccamkoy   4096 Mar 16 01:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 ccamkoy ccamkoy   4096 Mar 16 01:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ccamkoy ccamkoy 242840 Mar 16 01:39 IMG_2058_1024x768_Base64.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ccamkoy ccamkoy 182129 Mar 16 00:22 IMG_2058_1024x768.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ccamkoy ccamkoy    240 Mar 16 01:06 request.json
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$ cat request.json 
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "content":"/home/ccamkoy/aidat/IMG_5028_1064x768_Base64.jpeg"
      },
      "features":[
        {
         "type":"OBJECT_LOCALIZATION",
         "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$ curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"  -H "x-goog-user-project: cogent-anvil-417312" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data-binary -d @request.json "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: request.json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unable to parse number.\n-d\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
ccamkoy@cloudshell:~/aidat (cogent-anvil-417312)$
```

I tried:

> "content":"https://storage.cloud.google.com/aidat/IMG_2058_1024x768_Base64.jpeg"

but it did not work either :(

Maybe I'm doing a simple mistake but I can not see yet ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem finally. "request.json" file needs to be as below:

```
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "source":{
          "imageUri":
            "gs://aidat/IMG_2058_1024x768_Base64.jpeg"
        }
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"OBJECT_LOCALIZATION",
          "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```